# Пользовательская многоуровневая сортировка данных в таблице

Tags: c#, сортировка, mvvm-light

В таблицу выводятся данные, в каждой строке один объект, каждое его свойство - столбец в таблице. Нужно сделать пользовательскую сортировку по типу Excel - несколько задаваемых пользователем уровней сортировки. Данные во вью модели лежат в ObservableCollection, над ней создан ListCollectionView, для возможности фильтрации, сортировки, группировки, и уже этот ListCollectionView связывается с таблицей через ItemsSource. ListCollectionView поддерживает произвольную сортировку ([вот тут нашел](https://web.archive.org/web/20120311104106/http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=24)). Но не могу понять, как мне всё это совместить? Как именно написать компаратор по произвольным полям?

Answer (score 0):

После долгих разбирательств найдено решение, надеюсь кому-нибудь поможет.

1. Для ListCollectionView в свойство CustomSort надо передать экземпляр класса, реализующего интерфейс IComparer.
2. Реализация IComparer.Compare(object x, object y) должна быть примерно такая:

   public int Compare(object x, object y)
   {
       // Предварительная сортировка
       if (x == null && y != null)
       {
           return -1;
       }
       else if (x == y)
       {
           return 0;
       }
       else if (x != null && y == null)
       {
           return 1;
       }

   ```
   // Основная сортировка
   var result = 0;

   var firstOrder = x as OrderProxy;
   var secondOrder = y as OrderProxy;

   if (firstOrder != null && secondOrder != null)
   {
       foreach (var sortLevel in sortLevels)
       {
           var firstOrderProperty = firstOrder.GetType().GetProperty(sortLevel.ColumnProperty.NameDB);
           var secondOrderProperty = secondOrder.GetType().GetProperty(sortLevel.ColumnProperty.NameDB);

           var firstOrderValue = firstOrderProperty.GetValue(firstOrder, null);
           var secondOrderValue = secondOrderProperty.GetValue(secondOrder, null);

           switch (firstOrderProperty.PropertyType.ToString())
           {
               case "System.Int32":
                   var firstInt = (int)firstOrderValue;
                   var secondInt = (int)secondOrderValue;
                   result = InternalCompare(firstInt, secondInt);
                   break;

               case "System.Double":
                   var firstDouble = (double)firstOrderValue;
                   var secondDouble = (double)secondOrderValue;
                   result = InternalCompare(firstDouble, secondDouble);
                   break;

               case "System.String":
                   var firstString = (string)firstOrderValue;
                   var secondString = (string)secondOrderValue;
                   result = InternalCompare(firstString, secondString);
                   break;

               case "System.Boolean":
                   var firstBool = (bool)firstOrderValue;
                   var secondBool = (bool)secondOrderValue;
                   result = InternalCompare(firstBool, secondBool);
                   break;

               default:
                   throw new ArgumentException("При пользовательской сортировке встретился неучтёный тип данных.");
           }

           // В случае, если сравнение по текущему свойству дало результат, что объекты не равны, возвращаем этот результат.
           // В случае равных свойств продолжаем сортировку по следующим столбцам.
           if (result != 0)
           {
               return result;
           }
       }
   }

   return result;
   ```

   }

   /// 
   /// Метод сравнения объектов реализующих интерфейс IComparable
   /// 
   /// Тип данных
   /// Первый сравниваемый объект
   /// Второй сравниваемый объект
   /// Результат сравнения
   private int InternalCompare (T first, T second)
       where T : IComparable
   {
       return first.CompareTo(second);
   }